# How to remove all application data on react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

How to remove all application data on react native?

Not only `AsyncStorage.clear()`.
I mean deleting application data like through settings > application.
I have faced EUNSPECIFIED error code with `react-native-fbsdk`.

First I logged in with my facebook account,
Second I logged out from it,
Third I relogin with this account (It works well)
And then I logged out again,
And I tried to log in with another facebook account,
But I faced EUNSPECIFIED error.

But after deleting all app data (not uninstall) through settings > application,
I can login with another facebook account.

I have to delete all applilcation data when logged out from my react native application. 
OR
I have to fix this `react-native-fbsdk`'s bug (or I guess fbsdk is caching some data....)

Already I put `AsyncStorage.clear()` when logout, No changes..

Appreciate for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem with FBSDK as well and the problem is that when you login with facebook, the SDK creates an AccessToken linked to the old user. Therefore, when you try to login with another account, it throws this weird error message.

What you have to do is to logout the user on the fbAPI. The code below is how you do it:

```
// Remove FbAccessToken when the user logout.
logoutFromFB(){
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        LoginManager.logOut()
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Oh~~~ my god!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you!!!!
Verrry verrry much................

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Comment: Even if I logout with this function, If I try loging right after, it does not ask for login and password, but login me through my usual account. Any idea ?

Comment: You probably have to log out from your Facebook App on your phone.